# Animating custom view(leaf node in ViewHierarchy ) using ObjectAnimator is not smooth in android

Tags: android, animation

I am working in one slides based application and have created a shape using custom RelativeLayout and that is is very deep node in my application(position is about 90th level in viewHierarchy).And the shape is as content of the slides.
And while trying to animate translate , rotate or scale property of  the shape using ObjectAnimator or ViewPropertyAnimator.The animation is not smooth. its flickering.

Here is the sample code snip

`PropertyValuesHolder` pvhTX,pvhTY;
PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X,translateXFrom,translateXTo);

pvhTY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_Y, translateYFrom, translateYTo);

anim1 = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(shape, pvhTX, pvhTY);

anim1.setDuration((long) (animData.getDetail().getDuration() * 1000)); 
// Adding listener to override onAnimationStart,onAnimationEnd according to my requirement.
   anim1.addListener(new AnimationListener(shape, animData, slideEventHandler));

anim1.start();

In the above code
Shape is a customeView(custome relativlayout) it may be any geometrical shape like line circle cube triangle etc.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using some images in view you are animating, or it moves some images that are animating. If you used drawable folder for them then try to move them to folder drawable-nodpi. Coz when u use drawable dir it every time makes dpi transformation so it can cause low performance when animating.

here is sample:

```
public static void applyAnimation(Context context, View view, int animationResource, int animationOffsetMilisec){
        Animation anim = android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, animationResource);
        anim.setStartOffset(animationOffsetMilisec);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        if(view != null) {
            view.setAnimation(anim);
            view.startAnimation(anim);
        }
    }
```

then sample_animation.xml add to res.anim.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.1"
        android:toYScale="1.1"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
    <!--<alpha-->
    <!--android:fromAlpha="0.0"-->
    <!--android:toAlpha="1.0"-->
    <!--android:duration="1000" />-->
    <scale
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXScale="1.1"
        android:toXScale="0.91"
        android:toYScale="0.91"
        android:fromYScale="1.1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="100"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>


</set>
```

usage:

```
applyAnimation(context, yourview, R.anim.sample_animation, 0);
```

Comment: @stephan FYI problem is with all kind of filling of shape.
However shape can be filled with image, gradient or solid color.
but in all the cases flickering is happening.
i m trying with solid fill.
This is custom view. So is there any optimisation needed in drawing ??.
i checked the onDraw method of my custom shape, its getting called so many times.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: @Stephan 
Thanks for reply :-)
but it does not suits my requirement.I am doing animation using keyframe,PropertiesValueHolder and ObjectAnimator as per my requirement of my animation
So all these object i create before starting the animation
Please have an overview to my code snippet. and i am applying the animation to a my drawn shape which is customeView(child of relativelayout) and this view lies at the deepest level(90th level from root view). 
Animation is happening correctly which i apply but there is some flickering(not smooth) 
please help me in this regard
Thanks